# different ranges of x-axes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axes

How to switch the ticks on x-axes and not change the plot, please? I tried the lines that are commanded.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y2 = [1.2, 2, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.xlim(-2,2+max(len(x1), len(x2)))
plt.scatter(x1, x1, c= 'red')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green')

ax.tick_params(axis='x')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax3 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax3.set_xlim(-2,2+len(x1))
ax3.tick_params(axis='x')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', colors='green')
#ax.set_xlim(-2,2+len(x1))
#ax3.set_xlim(-2,2+len(x2))

plt.show()
```

I would like the range of -2,2+len(x1) for data x1 at the bottom axis and -2,2+len(x2) for x2 on the upper axis and spread it on the range of -2,2+max(len(x2), len(x1)).

[image]

The desired result is something like this (switched ticks and labels, please, do not take the wrong position on line axis into consideration):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y2 = [1.2, 2, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))


ax.tick_params(axis='x')
ax.scatter(x1, x1, c= 'red')
ax.set_xlim(-2,2+len(x1))


ax3 = ax.twiny()
ax3.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green')
ax3.tick_params(axis='x')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', colors='green')
ax3.set_xlim(-2,2+len(x2))

plt.show()
```